# How can I use the JConsole and JMX to do more than simply monitor my Java class?

Tags: java, jmx

I am learning how to use JMX, and I have this simple Java class that gobbles memory :

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class MemoryUsage  implements MemoryMBean 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Vector v = new Vector();
    while (true)
    {
      byte b[] = new byte[1048576];

      try {
         Thread.sleep(1200);
      } catch (InterruptedException ie){}


      v.add(b);
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      System.out.println( "free memory: " + rt.freeMemory() );
    }

  }

public void showCurrentTime() {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(time);

}

}
```

And when I set it up with JMX and use the JConsole, I can monitor the memory usage like this :

[image]

But is there anything more interesting that I can do with this? What if i wanted to do something that sounds more "smart" suchas  - stop/prevent the Java class from eating more memory after a certain threshold (say - 10 MB ). Or even to reduce the amount of memory being allocated , etc.  Does the JConsole itself allow you to do this? Or would I have to change the JMX code ?

How would you do add this into the JMX classes?

Comment: I suppose, but then the application would *fail*. I supposed you could restart it, but you run the risk of creating a feedback loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Ok understood.  But what is the feedback loop ? It will eat even more memory?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not; but it might start, eat too much memory and then immediately restart (ad infinitum).